# Is it possible to get controller from binding context

Tags: sapui5

I have one controller, for which I'am binding context data. I have the context ID to get the binding context and want to get corresponding controller. Is it possible?

Comment: Usually, we have same view and controller and we set different binding contexts. Binding context will never change the controller. Only the data is changed. Can you elaborate your problem a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as the [binding context](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.ContextBinding.html) is not aware of the controller.